# Is there a C++17 way to replace #define to achieve some function like partial in Python?

Tags: c++, c++17

If I have some code like:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void logger(const string& who, const string& where, Ts... args) {
    cout << "This is " << who << " in " << where << endl;
    //pseudocode
    cout << args... << endl;
}

class Base {
protected:
    string who = "Base";
public:
    Base() {}
    Base(const string& who):who(who){}
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    void func_Base(Ts... args) {
        logger(who, __FUNCTION__, args...);
    }
};
class A:public Base {
public:
    A() : Base("A") {};
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    void func_A(Ts... args) {
        logger(who, __FUNCTION__, args...);
    }
};
class B :public Base {
public:
    B() : Base("B") {};
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    void func_B(Ts... args) {
        logger(who, __FUNCTION__, args...);
    }
};
```

If I want to call `logger` in some derived class' function, I want to output its specified string `who` and its function's name.
But when I call `logger`, I will always need to pass `who` as the first parameter and `__FUNCTION__` as the second, so is there a way when I want to call `logger`, I will only write

```
logger(args...)
```

as if I called

```
#define logger(args...) logger(who, __FUNCTION__, args...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still one place where macros are still useful in C++. Until you switch to C++20 and can use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But how to omit the para `who`  in some way if not considering of macros like `__FUNCTION__`?

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work the way that you want it to work here, on a fundamental level, unfortunately.

Comment: If you can link your program with Boost and you cannot switch to C++20 you can use `boost::source_location` implementation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/assert/source_location.hpp